# No log4j library found after updating spring boot from 1.3.5 to 1.5.17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j

I upgraded spring boot from 1.3.5 to 1.5.17 and the log4j library is no longer found. 
The error says Error:(10, 24) java: package org.apache.log4j does not exist.
Here is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.17.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
     <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
     <version>0.8.2.2</version>
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring Boot 1.4, support for log4j 1.x has been dropped, as can be seen in the [release notes of Spring boot 1.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/spring-boot-1.4-release-notes):

> Log4j 1 support has been removed following [Apache EOL announcement](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces).

They recommend to upgrade to log4j 2.x, which can be done by using the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```